# Authenticating Domain users and Database users

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

My application has a page where authentication takes place. Here there are domain users and database users.

Application Process:

1.Firstly there will be a BUTTON to access the main page.
2.After clicking on the BUTTON. If they are domain users then they must be directed to the main page without asking Username and Password. If they are database users then a Login.aspx page must appear.

Problem:
My application is working fine when I run it on my system but after I deploy it to IIS the application is recognizing the Domain Name but its not recognizing the Username.

Code:

```
protected void btnOnline_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string account = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString();      
            //Response.Write("Server Domain Name " + Environment.UserDomainName);
            //Response.Write("<br/>");
            //Response.Write(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "<br/>");
            string Domain = "DomainUsers";
            if (account.Contains(Domain))
            {
                Response.Redirect("DomainUsers_Main.aspx");
                // Response.Write("Domain User");
            }
            else
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");

        }
    }
```

Comment: What exceptions are you receiving? Which line of code is not behaving as you expect that it should?

Comment: Keith Payne: The problem is with the IIS settings. When the Anonymous Authentication is Enabled its working fine for database users but its not directing to the main page for Domain users. And when Anonymous is disabled the domain users works and database users is not working.